# Ubuntu 13.10 Symfony installation date time issue

Tags: php, date, symfony, ubuntu, time

I'm installing Symfony on my Ubuntu system, everything was going fine until the very last moment when I was met with a screen that said:

```
ContextErrorException: Warning: date_default_timezone_get(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in /var/www/symfony-test/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 5107

    in /var/www/symfony-test/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 5107
    at ErrorHandler->handle('2', 'date_default_timezone_get(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone.', '/var/www/symfony-test/app/cache/dev/classes.php', '5107', array('level' => '100', 'message' => 'Notified event "kernel.exception" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelException".', 'context' => array()))
    at date_default_timezone_get() in /var/www/symfony-test/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 5107
    at Logger->addRecord('100', 'Notified event "kernel.exception" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelException".', array()) in /var/www/symfony-test/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 5193
    at Logger->debug('Notified event "kernel.exception" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelException".') in /var/www/symfony-test/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php line 246
    at TraceableEventDispatcher->preListenerCall('kernel.exception', array(object(ProfilerListener), 'onKernelException')) in /var/www/symfony-test/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php line 448
    at TraceableEventDispatcher->Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\{closure}(object(GetResponseForExceptionEvent))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(GetResponseForExceptionEvent)) in /var/www/symfony-test/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 1667
    at EventDispatcher->doDispatch(array(object(Closure), object(Closure)), 'kernel.exception', object(GetResponseForExceptionEvent)) in /var/www/symfony-test/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 1600
    at EventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.exception', object(GetResponseForExceptionEvent)) in /var/www/symfony-test/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 1764
    at ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.exception', object(GetResponseForExceptionEvent)) in /var/www/symfony-test/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php line 139
    at TraceableEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.exception', object(GetResponseForExceptionEvent)) in /var/www/symfony-test/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2870
    at HttpKernel->handleException(object(ContextErrorException), object(Request), '1') in /var/www/symfony-test/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2823
    at HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true) in /var/www/symfony-test/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2947
    at ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true) in /var/www/symfony-test/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2249
    at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in /var/www/symfony-test/web/app_dev.php line 28
```

After many hours of trying ideas in other threads, editing php.ini and classes.php to something that might work, I have gotten absolutely nowhere!  Has anyone else had this problem

**EDIT!** The plot thickens!

So I cleared the cache via the terminal, and I got an error relating to classes.php, which apparently is to do with permissions, so I sorted that as per the instructions on Symfony's site, and now guess what's happened?  We're back to square one, only this time I can't clear my cache to make it go away.  Yet, after I do clear the cache instead of it being php.ini, it's instead Logger.php, locating in /vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog, but then after a refresh it's back to php.ini

**SOLVED**

I feel like a bit of an idiot here! I didn't realise .ini files used ';' to indicate a comma, therefore every line in my php.ini file was a comment.  I removed the semi-colon and now it all works

Comment: Editing classes.php?  What is that all about?

Comment: I just thought since the error was there maybe I could find something.  I didn't :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the timezone string in the php.ini.  I strongly recommend that your server be configured to use UTC and then your setting should be:

```
date.timezone = UTC
```

Restart your web server

Just to be double safe:

```
php app/console cache:clear
```

You might also have an issue finding the right php.ini.  Check these directories:

```
/etc/php5/apache2
/etc/php5/cli
```

Ubuntu tends to separate out php.ini's for the command line vs mod_php, vs cgi, and there are directories for each. If you're not sure which php.ini is being loaded, there is php -i for the cli and the phpinfo(); program you can put in a quick script under your webroot.  Each will provide you information on the location of the php.ini that is being loaded.

Comment: the above cache clear defaults to the dev environment which I assume is what you are trying to get working initially.  You would access that using app_dev.php.  If you're trying prod (not recommended until you understand things better and have it installed) then php app/console cache:clear --env=prod

Comment: Tried UTC, should it have a ; after it?  I tried both ways, but there was one in there initially.

The app/console code is for the Symfony console right?  Which I can't access because I can't access app_dev.  Unless there is a way to do it through the terminal, I'll try and find that now.

Comment: Did you modified the `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` file or another one?

Comment: No semicolon at the end.  Exactly as I wrote it, is how you want it to be.  Semicolons in those ini files actually indicate comments.

Comment: Also, yes php app/console is the console program that runs command line utilities that help you do various things in symphony.  Run php app/console by itself to get a help listing.  That should work regardless of whether or not the default site works.  As far as ubuntu is concerned, there might be separate php.ini files for the command line php and mod_php or whatever you're using for web server integration.

Comment: In case this is purely an ubuntu/php environment/setup issue I added some instructions to help you debug why your configuration changes might not be taking effect.

Answer (score 1):

Set the date/timezone in php.ini but make sure you clear your cache before running your code again.
Symfony 2 cache clear is required as the classes.php is created by Symfony.
From the main project dir 
    app/console cache:clear --env=dev

Comment: That hasn't worked either sorry, I assume you meant clearing the actual browser cache?  I also restarted apache after every change (I tried UTC, Europe/London for example) and none of these worked either.

Comment: The Symfony cache as indicated in gviews answer - assuming Symfony2 - app/console cache:clear --env=dev|prod